# Why is the scatter Circle Color not resulting in a rainbow?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I am trying to follow this example from Matlab about coloring scatter points as a rainbow, while the x-position of the points is progressing towards the right side.

Here under "Vary Circle Color":
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html

```
x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);
y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);
c = linspace(1,10,length(x));
scatter(x,y,[],c)
```

[image]

While c as a variable goes from 1 to 20 with 200 interpolations. I am trying to replicate this for my piece of code, but I keep getting random color and the x-axis isn't matching the rainbow distribution as this:

```
g = 6;
pt_x = [0, g, -g]; 
pt_y = [g, -g, -g];

sz = 10;
loop = 100;

% var(1, loop) = 0;
% c = linspace(-10,10,length(var));
% c = 1:loop;
c = -loop/2:1:loop/2 -1;

rand_x = randi([-g,g],1,1);
rand_y = randi([-g,g],1,1);

for i = 1:loop
    r = randi([1,3],1,1);
    x1 =  (rand_x + pt_x(r)) / 2;
    y1 =  (rand_y + pt_y(r)) / 2;

    seq_x(1, i) = x1;
    seq_y(1, i) = y1;

    rand_x = x1;
    rand_y = y1;
end
scatter(seq_x, cos(seq_x),[],c, 'filled');
```

[image]

What am I missing here exactly? I would appreciate any help!

Expected to get a rainbow pattern
It resulted in a random pattern

Comment: Sort `seq_x`. Or set `c = seq_x`. Either way you’ll have a `c` that is proportional to the x location of the dot.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It worked! Maybe write this is an answer, so I can give your credit for solving the issue :)